# How to stop a node js server running as service

Tags: node.js, linux

I wrote a little server in node js, that I start as service when booting

My /etc/init.d/lightserver looks like this:

```
# Actions
case "$1" in
    start)
        # START
        /usr/bin/lightserver
        ;;
    stop)
        # STOP
        ;;
    restart)
        # RESTART
        ;;
esac
exit 0
```

I want to be able to stop the server properly with the command "/etc/init.d/lightserver stop". Without using of kill or killall.

How to implement this function into my server?

```
var i = 0;
var connect = require('connect'); 
var sleep = require('sleep');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var j = 1;

var server = connect().
use(function(req, res) {
    i++;
    res.write('Hello World! ' + i); 
    res.end();
    let code = 83028 + j; 
    j = 1 - j;
    exec("./433Utils/RPi_utils/codesend " + code, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
    });
}).listen(64084); 
console.log("Server has started and is listening to http://localhost:64084/");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this?

```
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  // some other cleanup code
  server.close();
});
```

What this does is intercept the kill command and close the server gracefully instead of just suddenly stopping the process, without warning.

To end the process gracefully you can just use the `kill <PID>` command, since `SIGTERM` is the default value. But if you want to be sure the sigterm is used you can always choose to use `kill -SIGTERM <PID>`, which will send a `SIGTERM`

> The  default  signal  for  kill is TERM. Use -l or -L to list available
>          signals.  Particularly useful signals include  HUP,  INT,  KILL,  STOP,
>          CONT,  and  0.   Alternate  signals  may be specified in three ways: -9
>          -SIGKILL -KILL.  Negative PID  values  may  be  used  to  choose  whole
>          process  groups;  see the PGID column in ps command output. A PID of -1
>          is special; it indicates all processes except the kill  process  itself
>          and init.

http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/kill1.html

Comment: Yes. And how could look the stop command in /etc/init.d/lightserver ?

Comment: I have update my answer, but you can basically use the kill or killall command, you cannot get around those commands (well there are ways, such as commands through sockets, but that is not the linux way).

Comment: and how to know PID? Is an another way except of `ps -eF | grep lightserver`?
or should write my server its current PID into a file?

Comment: The server is running, but pidof lightserver returns nothing. Do you know, why?

Comment: It is probably under node if you have not changed it.  Have you set `process.title  = 'lightserver'`?